# Как сделать, чтобы некоторые функции бота работали только после подписки на определённые тг каналы?

Tags: python, telebot

Создаю телеграмм бота и хочу чтобы, функции бота не работали, пока человек не подпишется на определённые телеграмм каналы. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Можно попробовать завести БД, и проверять подписан ли человек по его ID. Если да, то выполняется функция, если нет, то ему приходит сообщение по типу: "Данная функция будет доступна только после подписки"

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете библиотеку aiogram, тогда вы можете использовать следующий метод

```
sub_channel = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='@chatid', user_id=user_id)
```

`user_id` вы можете получить из `message.from_user.id`

Если вы используете telebot, тогда метод будет тот же самый, только без
`async` и всё это, разумеется, нужно будет поместить в `if`

```
user_status = ['creator', 'administrator', 'member']
for i in user_status:
    if i == bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=my_channel_id, user_id=message.from_user.id).status:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вам доступные функции")
```